# foreign key not updated in one to many hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

> User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PK_USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_USER_ID",referencedColumnName="PK_USER_ID")
    private Set<DeviceInfo> deviceInfos;
}
```

> DeviceInfo

```
@Entity
@Table(name="device_info")
public class DeviceInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="DEVICE_ID")
    private Integer deviceId;

    @Column(name="DEVICE_KEY")
    private String deviceKey;
    @Column(name="FK_USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;
}
```

When i try to insert data into user table and device_info table, data is inserted but foreign key column of device_info table not updated with primary key of user table.

Hibernate version:4.3.6.Final
Spring version :4.3.1

Comment: Before you save, you are doing this? deviceInfor.setUserId(userId.getId());

Comment: when i save user then it generate userId and hibernate internally save this id in device_info table but it will not update

Comment: session.save(user);

Comment: Hibernate: insert into user (PUSH_NOTIFICATION_STATUS, ACCESS_TOKEN, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MOBILE_NUMBER, OTP, PASSWORD, PROFILE_HIDE_STATUS, SIGNUP_DATE_TIME, SOCIAL_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_info (DEVICE_KEY, DEVICE_TOKEN, DEVICE_TYPE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, FK_USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: You are saving the user first, right? session.save(user), and them you get the user and set to device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @ManyToOne mapping is missing in your entity DeviceInfo

### User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PK_USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<DeviceInfo> deviceInfos;
}
```

### DeviceInfo.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="device_info")
public class DeviceInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="DEVICE_ID")
    private Integer deviceId;

    @Column(name="DEVICE_KEY")
    private String deviceKey;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PK_USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you missed setting user Object in deviceInfo object before persisting, code should look like:

```
user.setDeviceInfo(setOfDeviceInfo);

deviceInfo.setUser(user);

session.save(user);
```